# Getting data from one jsp to another

Tags: java, jsp, dictionary, attributes

```
Map<String, String> vignetteContent2 = buildVignetteContent2(
            actionState, "reenrolmentSummary");

    actionState.request.setAttribute("memberName", member.getFirstName());
    actionState.request.setAttribute("confirmNum", PayrollDedutionTransactionHelper.getConfirmationNumber());
    actionState.request.setAttribute("effectiveDate", getDisplayDateInMMMMDYYYY(PayrollDedutionTransactionHelper.getTransactionEffectiveDate(), actionState.getLanguageCode()));
    actionState.request.setAttribute("reenrolWelcome", reenrolmentSesssionData.getPayrollDeductionPageData());
    actionState.request.setAttribute("assetConsolidationAllowed",actionState.appSecurityManager.isAssetConsolidationAllowed(actionState.session));
    actionState.request.setAttribute("vignetteContent2", vignetteContent2);

    pageData.put("hubToolName", hubToolName);
    actionState.jspPageData = pageData;

    return true;
```

I want to get attribute confirmNum and effectiveDate in some other jsp. 
I tried this, but i know this is incorrect. Please also explain how we made this map and how we are getting the data.

```
function setDateAndConfirmation(paymentMethod){
            var date = new Date($.now());
//          var dateString = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd M yy', date);
            var hours = date.getHours();
            if(hours < 10){
                hours = "0" + hours;
            }
            var minutes = date.getMinutes();
            if(minutes < 10){
                minutes = "0"+minutes;
            }
            var seconds = date.getSeconds();
            if(seconds < 10){
                seconds = "0" + seconds;
            }
            $("#dateSubmitted").effectiveDate;


            $("#confNumber").confirmNum;
        }

        setDateAndConfirmation("P");
```

Comment: What the....."Please also explain how we made this map and how we are getting the data" ?? lol. To get the data either map to class or use a design pattern that stores the data (eg service layer) before sending and call this from the other method.

Comment: man i have just started working on java few weeks back. So if it sounds funny to you, then i apologize.

Comment: I understand. Just the way you mentioned it was funny. Do you know how to store data, or map data to a class and retrieve it? It may be helpful.

Comment: Yes, i know we use put method to allocate certain value to a key. and we can use iterator to retrieve it. This is just the basic stuff i know.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use something like this in your controller:

```
@ModelAttribute("confirmNum")
protected String confirmNum(HttpSession session){

       return PayrollDedutionTransactionHelper.getConfirmationNumber();

    }
```

Then in your other JSP (view) call the attribute just like your initial JSP and other views.